# Opencart 2 Display a customers variable on product detail page

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I am using Opencart 2.1.0.2 and I added a new column to the customer mysql table. I need to when the customer views a products detail page to display the unique value from the customers mysql customer row. However I am getting the below error

Notice: Undefined variable: mypaycheckschedule in public_html/catalog/view/theme/rgen-opencart/template/product/product.tpl on line 165

Below is my code (I am not sure what I am missing)

File: public_html/catalog/model/catalog/product.php

```
public function getProduct($product_id) {
            //see if user is logged in and if so get a custom variable to show on product detail page
            if($this->customer->isLogged()) 
              {
                  $queryb = $this->db->query("SELECT paycheckschedule FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer WHERE customer_id = '" . $this ->customer->getId() ."'");
                  if($queryb->row['paycheckschedule'] =='')
                    {
                       $queryb->row['paycheckschedule'] = 'none';
                    }
              }
               else
              {
                  $queryb->row['paycheckschedule'] = 'n/a';
              }
```

I then have in the same file

```
        if ($query->num_rows) {
        return array(
            'product_id' => $query->row['product_id'],
            'mypaycheckschedule'  => $queryb->row['paycheckschedule'], 
            'name' => $query->row['name'],
```

Then in my
public_html/catalog/controller/product/product.php

```
$data['products'][] = array(
                'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
                'thumb'       => $image,
                'name'        => $result['name'],
                'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, $this->config->get('config_product_description_length')) . '..',
                'price'       => $price,
                'special'     => $special,
                'mypaycheckschedule' => $result['mypaycheckschedule'],
                'pre_pay_discount' => $result['pre_pay_discount'],
                'tax'         => $tax,
                'minimum'     => $result['minimum'] > 0 ? $result['minimum'] : 1,
                'rating'      => $rating,
                'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $result['product_id'])
            );
```

Then in my
public_html/catalog/view/theme/rgen-opencart/template/product/product.tpl

```
<?php  echo $mypaycheckschedule; ?>
```

Comment: **`'mypaycheckschedule' => $result['mypaycheckschedule']`**

Comment: So Rahul I am putting the above in my public_html/catalog/model/catalog/product.php file correct? because that did not seem to make a difference

Comment: `public_html/catalog/controller/product/product.php`

Comment: Please see my edited original post above as I edited it with the error message I am now getting

Comment: Check your model code. Do a `print_r($queryb->row)` and check whether it is returning `paycheckschedule`

Comment: So yes I see it is returning Array ( [paycheckschedule] => n/a )  and thats good it should return an  n/a right now since I am viewing the product detail page and am not logged in.

Comment: Check the return of `print_r($result)` in `public_html/catalog/controller/product/product.php`

Comment: So I added

print_r($result);
die();
right above the
$data['mypaycheckschedule'] = $result['paycheckschedule'];

However nothing seems to be displayed? However I then tried to put echo "test";
print_r($result);
die();
and do not even see my text?

Comment: `foreach ($results as $result) { 
    print_r($result); ...`

Comment: I got it working thanks for the help!!